# What's the difference between "be careful about/of/with/in"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions

What's the difference between *be careful about/of/with/in*?

I am confused about which preposition is correct in the following sentence:

> *My secretary is so careful in/of her work that none has so far found any error in her work.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are used slightly differently.

"About" is normally followed by "the" (as below)

> *About:* My secretary is so careful *about* **the way she does** her work that no one has so far found an error in her work.

"Of" is normally followed by whatever bad thing that we are being careful towards, in this case making errors (as below)

> *Of:* My secretary is so careful *of* **making errors** that no one has so far found an error in her work.

"With" and "in" refer to whatever process someone is being careful during (as below)

> *With:* My secretary is so careful *with* her work that no one has so far found an error in her work.
>
> *In:* My secretary is so careful *in* her work that no one has so far found an error in her work.